# Как выпустить луч под определённым углом в трехмерном пространстве?

Tags: python, геометрия, 3d

Вот пример в 2D:

```
def ray(x, y, angle, step):
    new_x = x + sin(angle) * step
    new_y = y + cos(angle) * step
    return new_x, new_y
```

Comment: Добавить z, очевидно же.

Comment: @Эникейщик, и что же будет в z, sin или cos?

Comment: @MarianD а это зависит от того, что будет в angle2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В 3D будут фигурировать 2 угла - я не буду их называть `angle` и `angle2`, а использую для них знакомые имена `azimuth` и `zenith` (угол между осью *z*):

```
def ray(x, y, z, azimuth, zenith, step):
    new_x = x + sin(zenith) * cos(azimuth) * step
    new_y = y + sin(zenith) * sin(azimuth) * step
    new_z = z + cos(zenith) * step
    return new_x, new_y, new_z
```

т.к. ваш угол `angle` в плоскости *xy* я переименовал на `azimuth` и проекция вектора в плоскость *xy* будет иметь длину `sin(zenith) * step`.

---

Когда вы вместо угла между осей *z* хотите угол между плоскостью *ху* (elevation), примените:

```
def ray(x, y, z, azimuth, elevation, step):
    new_x = x + cos(elevation) * cos(azimuth) * step
    new_y = y + cos(elevation) * sin(azimuth) * step
    new_z = z + sin(elevation) * step
    return new_x, new_y, new_z
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

*Примечание:*

В вашем примере `angle` - угол  от оси *y*, в моем ответе `azimuth` - от оси *x*, как видно на картинке.

В случае необходимости поменяйте местами `cos(azimuth)` и `sin(azimuth)`, чтобы получить правильные функции для азимута от оси *y*.

Comment: Также может быть полезно задание не углов, а направляющего вектора `(dx, dy, dz)`